# PHP - Populate array with checkbox array values stored in session

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I'm hitting a wall here. I'm using Paypal Parallel Payment API (PHP) and I want to populate the array `$receiverEmailArray` inside `parallel.php` with checkbox array data (email addresses) stored in `$_SESSION['owneremails']`

```
$receiverEmailArray = array(
        ''.$_SESSION['owneremails'].'',
        'sales@mydomain.com'
        );
```

I would like the owner email addresses to populate inside `$receiverEmailArray` (`sales@mydomain` is a constant) and in the end look as such:

```
$receiverEmailArray = array(
        'owneremail1@gmail.com', 'owneremail2@gmail.com', 'owneremail3@gmail.com',
        'sales@mydomain.com'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$_SESSION['owneremails']` is an array of email addresses, you can just add your constant email address:

```
$_SESSION['owneremails'][] = 'sales@mydomain.com';
$receiverEmailArray = $_SESSION['owneremails'];
```

If `$_SESSION['owneremails']` isn't an array, can you edit your question to show the contents?